# access child elements of another parent in jquery

Tags: jquery

My Code structure is like

```js
$(".nav-link.active").closest(".nav-item").prev().children(".nav-link").css({
  background: "red"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h1>Maecenas nec ante a justo fringilla luctus</h1>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"><span class="check__circle"></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active">
      <span class="check__circle"></span> Profile
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">
      <span class="check__circle__checkmark"></span>Profile
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

when nav-link active is clicked I need to access the check__circle of the previous parent can anybody help me with this

Comment: I have made a snippet. It's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".nav-link.active").parents(".nav-item").prev().find(".nav-link").css({
  background: "red"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <h1>Maecenas nec ante a justo fringilla luctus</h1>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"><span class="check__circle">hello</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active">
      <span class="check__circle"></span> Profile
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">
      <span class="check__circle__checkmark"></span>Profile
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet works fine. Only thing is to add the code inside the click function

```
$(".nav-link.active").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".nav-item").prev().children(".nav-link").css({ background: "red" });
});
```

To access the `check__circle`,

```
$(".nav-link.active").click(function() {
  var previous = $(this).closest(".nav-item").prev();
  previous.css({
    background: "red"
  });
  previous.find('.check__circle'); //Access the class and do what you need.
});
```